# Rubocop Hash Alignmnt

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Currently Rubocop accepts both these formats as correct

```
# good
do_something(foo: 1,
             bar: 2)

# good
do_something(
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
)
```

How can I change rubocop's config to accept only the latest?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that using the [MultilineHashBraceLayout](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.46.0/RuboCop/Cop/Style/MultilineHashBraceLayout) and the [FirstHashElementLineBreak](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.46.0/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FirstHashElementLineBreak) cops in the following combination should lead to the desired format.

```
Layout/FirstHashElementLineBreak:
  Enabled: true
Layout/MultilineHashBraceLayout:
  Enabled: true
  EnforcedStyle: new_line
```

Comment: thanks for answering, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work: https://imgur.com/a/xxvjLES